# Looping through array of objects and returning object with same/key value pairs as another object

Tags: javascript

The goal is to see if the first argument has any of the same key/value pairs as the second argument. This is what I have come up with but it doesn't work. I've been stuck on this for quite a long time. Would be helpful if you pointed out errors in logic without giving me the solution.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  for(i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if(Object.keys(collection[i]) && Object.values(collection[i]) === Object.keys(source) && Object.values(source)) {
    return collection[i];
    }   
  }
}
​
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What exactly happens, and how is it different from your expected result?

Comment: does the source has only one key?

Answer (score 0):

With only one key in source, you could get it and perform a find with checking the value of the actual item and with the given value of `source`. Then the first found object is returned.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var key = Object.keys(source)[0];
    return collection.find(o => o[key] === source[key]);
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Montague" }));
```

With more than one key, you could check all keys for sameness.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var keys = Object.keys(source);
    return collection.find(o => keys.every(k => o[k] === source[k]));
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], {  first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }));
```